# Projecting a path homotopy "down" with a covering map. Do we also get a path homotpy?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

Consider we have two spaces $X$ and $\tilde X$ and a covering map, $p\colon \tilde X \to X$.

Let's say we have two paths $\tilde f$ and $\tilde g$  in $\tilde X$ that are lifts of $f$ and $g$, in $X.$
Assume that $\tilde f$ and $\tilde g$ are path homotopic. Then, are $f$ and $g$ path homotopic?

My intuituion tells me that we can project the homotopy that connects $\tilde f$ to $\tilde g$ down to our original space - but what confirms that this projected homotopy will, in fact, be a homotopy of paths that connects $f$ and $g?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A path homotopy in $\tilde X$ is just a particular kind of continuous function taking values in $\tilde X$, namely $H : [0,1] \times [0,1] \to \tilde X$.

The composition of continuous functions is continuous, so $p \circ H : [0,1] \times [0,1] \to X$ is continuous.

Now all you have to observe is that since $f = p \circ \tilde f$ and $g = p \circ \tilde g$, and since $\tilde H$ is a path homotopy between $\tilde f$ and $\tilde g$, it follows that $H$ is a path homotopy between $f$ and $g$. All you have to do is plug in certain values of $(s,t) \in [0,1] \times [0,1]$ and check certain equations; for instance, knowing that $\tilde H(s,0)=\tilde f(s)$, applying $p$ to both sides of the equation it follows that $H(s,0)=f(s)$.